# SQL Given start date and end date, with total, I need to split it into days

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple table in postgress.

It has a start date, end date and total volume

example 1 Jan 2016, 31 Dec 2016 and 360,0000

I need to split in into the following output

```
1 Jan 2016 360000/366
2 Jan 2016 360000/366

...
..
..
31 Dec 2016 360000/366
```

366 is the no of days in 2016

The ouput needs to be sent to another table.  What's the simplest way to do this? Some spans across 20-30 years.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you show us the schema for both tables please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `generate_series()`:

```
with const as (
      select '2016-01-01'::date as date_start, '2016-12-31'::date as date_end, 360000 as amt
     )
select g.dte, amt / (date_end - date_start + 1.0)
from const, lateral
     generate_series(date_start, date_end, interval '1 day') as g(dte) ;
```

Lateral joins are not supported in all versions of Postgres, so you can also do:

```
select generate_series(date_start, date_end, interval '1 day') as dte,
       amt / (date_end - date_start + 1.0)
from const
```

Comment: You don't really need the `lateral` keyword. `from const, generate_series(1...)` will work on earlier versions just as well

Comment: Thanks. Let me give this a try.